# Axios PUT request is sending no data to the server

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, axios

I am working on updating data in the database via C# web API. The data object is being passed to C# web API controller action from React.js front end on button click.

I implemented the `axios` library to cater `GET`, and `PUT` requests. I have pretty much covered most issues like `CORS`. When the button is clicked, I see data being constructed in the console but on the controller side it is `null`.

I am posting the work that so far I developed and triaged. I have attached a few snapshots to share that React front end is giving a 200 (OK) response and the web API is giving `null`. Is there any issue with any naming convention?

A side note - axios GET works without any issues. Can I get some help here?

React.js code:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Insight() {
  let { state } = useLocation();
  const [st, setST] = useState([]);
  const [insight, setInsight] = useState({
    updatedInsight: "",
  });
  const putUrl = "http://localhost:5152/api/insight/update";
  let info = {
    InsightId: 7,
    Topic: "Main topic",
    Insight: "This area gives visual context",
  };

  function handleInsight(event) {
    setInsight({ updatedInsight: event.target.value });
  }

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios
      .put(
        putUrl,
        {
          body: JSON.stringify(info),
        },
        {
          headers: { accept: "*/*", "Content-type": "application/json" },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("info updated");
        console.log(info);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ${error}"));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <div className="tableMainCon">
          <span>Topic</span>
          <input type="text"></input>
          <h5>Insight:</h5>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            id="txtInsight"
            name="insight"
            rows="7"
            cols="10"
            name="insight"
            defaultValue={st.insight}
            title="insight"
            onChange={handleInsight}
          ></textarea>
          <br></br>
          <button onClick={onSubmit}>Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Insight;
```

C# Controller Code:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.EnableCors]
    public class InsightController : ControllerBase
    {

    [HttpPut]
        [Route("/api/insight/update")]
        public IActionResult Update(**[FromBody]** InsightDisplay model)
        {
            ProductInsights insight = new();
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    insight.Topic = model.Topic;
                    insight.InsightId = model.InsightId;
                    insight.Insight = model.Insight;

                    //Call data access layer to update table
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"model object is null");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return new JsonResult(result);
        }
}
```

C# Model Code:

```
public class InsightDisplay
{
    public long InsightId { get; set; }
    public string? Topic { get; set; }
    public string? Insight { get; set; }
}
```

[![Axios vs. fetch api comparison][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdYw5.png

Comment: By the time I posted this question, out of curiosity I tried implementing `fetch` API call to update the record and surprisingly it came out super fast than `Axios`. Wondering if I switch all the call to `fetch` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your axios call as below. You don't need to have a `body` with `JSON.stringify()`. Axios would do it internally.

```js
await axios.put(putUrl, info, {
  headers: { accept: "*/*", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});
```